# How to prevent focusout when focusin fires on the same element?

Tags: jquery, focusout, focusin

I'm attaching an .active class to a div that is wrapped around an input and label.

My problem is when an element is clicked inside the wrapped DIV, the focusout will fire, and this is causing a slight flicker of the styling.

```
$('body')
    .on('focusin', '.formlabel', function() {

        $(this).addClass('active');

    })
    .on('focusout', '.formlabel', function() {

        $('.formlabel').removeClass('active');

    });
```

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/mamacogimo/1/edit?html,js,output - click the label and an item from the dropdown. You will notice the blue background flickers.

Is there anyway to prevent the flickering?

Comment: Consider changing the target element of the focus to the `<input..>` instead of `.formlabel`.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't fix the issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timeout, like so:

```
var timeout;
$('body').on('focusin', '.formlabel', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');

  clearTimeout(timeout);

}).on('focusout', '.formlabel', function(e) {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.formlabel').removeClass('active');
  }, 250);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/dafubiweto/2/edit